# how to plot KMeans?

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means

I am trying to use MiniBatchKMeans with a larger data set and plot 2 different attributes. I am receive an `Keyerror: 2` I believe I am making an error in my `for` loop but I am not sure where. can someone help me see were my error is? I am running the following code:

```
import numpy as np ##Import necessary packages
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import *
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans 


url2="http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data" #Reading in Data from a freely and easily available source on the internet
Adult = pd.read_csv(url2, header=None, skipinitialspace=True) #Decoding data by removing extra spaces in cplumns with skipinitialspace=True
##Assigning reasonable column names to the dataframe
Adult.columns = ["age","workclass","fnlwgt","education","educationnum","maritalstatus","occupation",  
                 "relationship","race","sex","capitalgain","capitalloss","hoursperweek","nativecountry",
                 "less50kmoreeq50kn"]

print("reviewing dataframe:")
print(Adult.head()) #Getting an overview of the data
print(Adult.shape)
print(Adult.dtypes)

np.median(Adult['fnlwgt']) #Calculating median for final weight column
TooLarge = Adult.loc[:,'fnlwgt'] > 748495 #Setting a value to replace outliers from final weight column with median
Adult.loc[TooLarge,'fnlwgt']=np.median(Adult['fnlwgt']) #replacing values from final weight Column with the median of the final weight column
Adult.loc[:,'fnlwgt']


X = pd.DataFrame()
X.loc[:,0] = Adult.loc[:,'age']
X.loc[:,1] = Adult.loc[:,'hoursperweek']

kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters = 2)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print(centroids)
print(labels)

colors = ["g.","r."]

for i in range(len(X)):
    print("coordinate:",X[i], "label:", labels[i])
    plt.plot(X.loc[:,0][i],X.loc[:,1][i], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)

plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths = 5, zorder = 10)
plt.show()
```

When I run the `for` loop I only see 2 data points plotted in the scatter matrix. Do I need to call the points differently from the created data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid this problem by not running a loop to plot every single of the 32,000 points individually, which is bad practice and unnecessary. You can simply pass two arrays to `plt.scatter()` to make this scatter plot, there is no need for a loop. Use these lines:

```
colors = ["green","red"]

plt.scatter(X.iloc[:,0], X.iloc[:,1], c=np.array(colors)[labels], 
    s = 10, alpha=.1)

plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], marker = "x", s=150, 
    linewidths = 5, zorder = 10, c=['green', 'red'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Your original error was caused by a bad use of pandas indexing. You can replicate your error by doing that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list('dasdasas'))
df[1]
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still learning, trying to replicate some examples I have followed. I used MiniBatchKMeans to try and deal with not plotting all 32,000 points. Do you have a recommendation on how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Plotting isn't the problem. The problem was essentially creating 32,000 plots on top of each other. That's what you were doing with the loop.

Comment: Ok, Thank you I think I understand what was going on now.